# CarQuery auto database

Tags: cognito-forms

I'd like to use the CarQuery database of year/make/model in my Cognito form.

Can Cognito Forms be paired with CarQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we can not look up data in other systems, but this is a feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/vKfb0oVP). You can vote for this feature, and other features that you would like to see us work on for future Cognito Forms releases.